# Are getters for "field combinations" in Java DTO considered bad practice?

Tags: java, dto

It is "common sense" that a Java data transfer object (DTO) should not contain business logic, database access, etc. But how about getters which only evaluate fields in the DTO itself?

Given the following example, would this also be considered "bad practice"?

```java
@Getter
public class PaymentRequest {

    private Status status;
    private PaymentType paymentType;

    public boolean isPaymentTypeCreditcard() {
        return this.paymentType == PaymentType.CREDITCARD;
    }

    public boolean isStatusSuccess() {
        return this.status == Status.SUCCESS;
    }

    public boolean isSuccessfulCreditcardPayment() {
        return this.isPaymentTypeCreditcard() && this.isStatusSuccess();
    }
}
```

Comment: The whole point of a DTO is to aggregate data to be transferred over expensive calls( like network calls). Indeed, it is recommended not to contain any business logic, just the data. Now, I don't see anything bad in here, you're simply providing shortcuts (if you weren't providing `isStatusSuccess()`, I would have had to do `getStatus() == Status.SUCCESS` to have the same response). However, from a theoretical point of view, if I manipulate a DTO I only expect data and serialization/deseralization features. Any other thing may make me suspicious...

Comment: If your DTOs are auto-generated from schema files you'll want to avoid hand edits.